# PTIJ: What are some customs and traditions of the Yishletu Chasidim?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

I haven't met very many Yishletuers, and am looking to get some more information. From what I've heard, their name comes from "yesh l'tu", since they go out of their way to make sure they do each and every one of the lamed-tes melachos over the course of the week in order to truly be meoneg shabbos.

They also apparently have a minhag to ride atop their sheep on purim day because of the line from the megillah: "asher *yishletu*...heima *v'sonayhem*".

Aside from that, I haven't heard much about them, and I'm hoping someone here might be able to shed some light on the topic.

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).